# $mount_container/usr/bin/python3 :no such file or directory (buildah)

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, buildah

i have installed python 3 ..

when i do :

```
ls -ltr /usr/bin | grep python  (in buildah it will be $mount_container/usr/bin)
0 lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root      25 Jan  7 10:12 python3 -> /etc/alternatives/python3
0 lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root      31 Jun 22  2019 python3.6 -> /usr/libexec/platform-python3.6
0 lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root      32 Jun 22  2019 python3.6m -> /usr/libexec/platform-python3.6m
0 lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root      24 Jan  7 10:12 unversioned-python -> /etc/alternatives/python
```

but when i do

`$/usr/bin/python3`

it is saying "no such file or directory".

Note that i am running this inside a continer (using buildah , trying to build a docker which has python3)

if i do `$mount_continer/usr/bin/python3` it says "no such file or directory"

Comment: Are you typing the dollar?

Comment: in your console put : whereis python

Comment: No,sorry. That might be confusing. -bash-4.2$/usr/bin/python3

Comment: @GiovaniSalazar , it says /usr/bin/python3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
cd / (goes into root directory)
```

and then type

```
/usr/bin/python3
```

Now you must see the python interpreter.

**Explanation** - Python is generally found in the location `/usr/bin/`

`/usr/bin/python3` will simply invoke the python3 found inside `/usr/bin` but since you run the command from outside the root directory,the first directory i.e `/usr` is not found. `/home` and `/usr` are inside the root directory, and you are running the command from `/home` directory. Hope it helps.

Note:For Ubuntu 16.04